# Вылетает браузер после запуска кода c selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Имею следующий код для запуска браузера

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\\Users\Professional\Downloads\chromedriver.exe")

browser.get('https://www.google.co.uz/')
```

после запуска кода браузер открывается и сразу закрывается и я не вижу конечный результат. Помогите пожалуйста исправить

терминал выдает следующее сообщение

```
c:\Users\Professional\Documents\GitHub\Billing_private_viewer\test.py:7: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\\Users\Professional\Downloads\chromedriver.exe")

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52505/devtools/browser/db52f3a7-ea38-4d0c-8379-5050a65d0296
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Professional\Documents\GitHub\Billing_private_viewer\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\\Users\Professional\Downloads\chromedriver.exe")
  File "C:\Users\Professional\Documents\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "google",
  File "C:\Users\Professional\Documents\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 93, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Professional\Documents\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 268, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Professional\Documents\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 359, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Professional\Documents\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Professional\Documents\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 99
Current browser version is 97.0.4692.99 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x011FCF43+2608963]
        Ordinal0 [0x0118E8C1+2156737]
        Ordinal0 [0x010842C8+1065672]
        Ordinal0 [0x010A3FC5+1195973]
        Ordinal0 [0x0109FC0F+1178639]
        Ordinal0 [0x0109D4D1+1168593]
        Ordinal0 [0x010CFC2F+1375279]
        Ordinal0 [0x010CF85A+1374298]
        Ordinal0 [0x010CAED6+1355478]
        Ordinal0 [0x010A5D86+1203590]
        Ordinal0 [0x010A6C66+1207398]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x013A3252+1679186]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0145591C+2410012]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x01293B41+567361]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x01292CC6+563654]
        Ordinal0 [0x01194B5B+2181979]
        Ordinal0 [0x01199AA8+2202280]
        Ordinal0 [0x01199B95+2202517]
        Ordinal0 [0x011A3B2C+2243372]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x775EFA29+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77737A9E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77737A6E+238]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в пути C:\ убрать один обратный слеш

```
>>> r"C:\\Users\Professional\Downloads\chromedriver.exe"
'C:\\\\Users\\Professional\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe'
```

Comment: спасибо, ваш вариант сработал

Answer (score 1):

Основное в ошибке:

```
This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 99
Current browser version is 97.0.4692.99
```

Поставьте `chromedriver.exe`, совместимый с версией `Chrome` на вашем компьютере. Или наоборот - установите версию `Chrome`, совместимую с хромдрайвером. Вместе работают только совместимые версии. У вас сейчас версия браузера стоит более старая, чем та, которая поддерживается хромдрайвером.

Comment: по вашему предложению нашёл совместимую версию дров отсюда  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65194694/session-not-created-this-version-of-chromedriver-only-supports-chrome-version-8/65194918 , но это лишь добавило пару секунд к ожиданию до закрытия